# pgfplots: weird output when plotting (x*cos^2(x))/(sin(x))

Tags: pgfplots

trying to plot `(x * cos^2(x)) / (sin(x))`

The output is very weird. Only a visual glitch. Does anyone know how to fix this?

MWE :

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

% The next line does not change anything
% \pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        domain=-2*pi:2*pi,
        axis lines = middle,
        axis equal image,
        width=14cm,
        enlargelimits={abs=0.4},
        no markers,
        samples=200,
    ]
    \addplot[domain=-2*pi:2*pi]{(x*cos(deg( x ))^2)/( sin( deg( x) ) )};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You might also look up [restrict y to domain=...] (page 395 pgfplots manual).

Comment: @JohnKormylo So far, that's probably the best way I was suggested, because it requires the less changes. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `dimension too large` (the division by zero around x=0). One solution is to split things like this:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

% The next line does not change anything
% \pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        domain=-2*pi:2*pi,
        ymin=-6, ymax=6,
        axis lines = middle,
        axis equal image,
        width=14cm,
        enlargelimits={abs=0.4},
        no markers,
        samples=199,
    ]
    \addplot[domain=0.2:2*pi]{(x*(cos(deg( x )))^2) /( sin( deg( x) ) )};
    \addplot[domain=-2*pi:-0.2]{(x*(cos(deg( x )))^2) /( sin( deg( x) ) )};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This is not perfect, as I don't like duplication. But it works correctly

Comment: @G'k (At)Rmano I do not think that the singularity at 0 is to blame (because there is none), but the others. Try `\begin{axis}[
        domain=-2*pi:2*pi,
        ymin=-6, ymax=6,
        axis lines = middle,
        axis equal image,
        width=14cm,
        enlargelimits={abs=0.4},
        no markers,
        samples=200,
    ]
    \addplot[domain=-2*pi:2*pi]{max(-7,min(7,(x*(cos(deg( x )))^2) /( sin( deg( x) ) )))};
    \end{axis}` to see what I mean.

Comment: @user231225 Yeah, I get it. That's another way to do it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you try to plot the function, no problem:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

% The next line does not change anything
 \pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
%        domain=-2*pi:2*pi,
%        axis lines = middle,
%        axis equal image,
        width=14cm,
        enlargelimits={abs=0.4},
        no markers,
        samples=100,
    ]
    \addplot{(x*cos(deg( x ))^2)/( sin( deg( x) ) )};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: graph of function]

Comment: Thanks. Do you know why it happens?

Comment: @G'k Sorry, no, as always I started making things more simple and to just answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

I can't really make this a comment as it's way too long. The two answers given are somewhat misleading because those almost vertical lines are not part of the graph. Additionally, the function is not defined at x=0. The graph of your function should look more like this:
[image]

This is closest to the accepted answer but the vertical lines are not part of the function and there is a hole at (0,1). The domain of your function will be the all values of x for which the denominator, sin(x), is not 0. That is x cannot be a multiple of pi. When that multiple of pi is nonzero, the graph has a vertical asymptote. When x=0, there is a removable discontinuity because the limit laws as well as the famous limit that sin(x)/x goes to 1 as x approaches 0. So there should be a hole at (0,1) to indicate the graph is not defined there. The code to produce is shown below. It makes use of John Kormylo's comment about `restrict y to domain`. This prevents the problem of the function going to infinity ruining the graph. Try removing that line and running it. You will get output similar to your posted code. The `dimension too large` error is caused by x=pi and x=-pi and not x=0.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{f}{1}{%
  \pgfmathparse{x*cos(deg(x))^2/sin(deg(x))}%
}
\tikzset{Line Style1/.style={smooth,thick, dashed,samples=400}}
\tikzset{Line Style2/.style={smooth,thick, samples=800}}
\pgfplotsset{holdot/.style={color=NavyBlue,fill=white,only marks,mark=*}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    restrict y to domain=-6.4:6.4,
    domain=-2*pi:2*pi,
    axis lines = middle,
    axis equal image,
    width=14cm,
    enlargelimits={abs=0.4},
    no markers,
    samples=200,
] 
\addplot[Line Style2, color=NavyBlue, domain=-6.4:6.4] (\x,{f(\x)}); 

\addplot[holdot] coordinates{(0,1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```